# How do I find and print the elements within an array that are bigger than a certain number?

Tags: python

Within a single dimension python array I want to print the elements that are higher than 14. Any ideas how I could do this?

Code I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np 
tempData = np.loadtxt("temperature.txt") 
for tempData > 14: 
    print(tempData)
```

Comment: i don't know how

Comment: start by checking out a for loop

Comment: us providing you the answer to an elemental question *doesn't* really help you understand it

Comment: that's why im asking how to do it, I've tried if statements and for loops which haven't worked for me

Comment: `I've tried this and that`: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: import numpy as np
tempData = np.loadtxt("temperature.txt")
for tempData > 14:
    print(tempData)

Comment: import numpy as np
tempData = np.loadtxt("temperature.txt")
if tempData > 14:
    print(tempData)

Comment: Obviously with proper indentation, and lines I don't know how to fix that on this

Comment: @TeresaDavenport, I have added your code to the main question section. Let me know if this is correct. Let's use this to get the conversation going.

Comment: @TeresaDavenport, you may want to loop at a few examples. Here are some of the examples to look at.... [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). [example-1](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_iterating.asp) and [example-2](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_filter.asp)

Comment: @TeresaDavenport, recommend you use websites like [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), [Geek4Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/), [learnPython](https://www.learnpython.org/en/) to name a few. Stack Overflow is to help from peers when you are struggling with coding issues. Please read this for more information. How to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called boolean indexing. [Read the official Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) for more information.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.loadtxt("temperature.txt")
mask = x > 14  # boolean mask
print(x[mask])  # print the values in `x` that are `True` in mask
```

The documentation has the following example:

```
>>> y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
>>> b = y>20
>>> y[b]
array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the below website:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_filter.asp

See if this will help you get what you want.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([41, 42, 43, 44])

filter_arr = arr > 42

newarr = arr[filter_arr]

print(filter_arr)
print(newarr)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[False False  True  True]
[43 44]
```